# Vue js: counter not working properly in my code

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

in my vue js code below i wanted to create animated number that counts from 0 to any number when page mounted, but  below code is not working.However, it works perfect in html,js and css project but in vue js its not showing any result someone help?

thanks in advance

```js
import $ from 'jquery'
export default {
mounted:
$('.counter').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        countTo = $this.attr('data-count');
    
    $({ countNum: $this.text()}).animate({
      countNum: countTo
    },
  
    {
  
      duration: 8000,
      easing:'linear',
      step: function() {
        $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
      },
      complete: function() {
        $this.text(this.countNum);

      }
  
    });  
    
    
  
  })
    
}
```

```html
<div class="row  sixthRow" data-aos="fade-up">
            
           
            <div class="col">
                <div class="counter" data-count="99">0 </div>
                <h4 class="count mt-3 mb-5"> Response Time</h4>
            </div>


  
            <div class="col" >
                
                <div class="counter" data-count="99">0</div>
                <h4 class="count mt-3 mb-5">Security</h4>
            </div>
           
          
            <div class="col" >
                <div class="counter" data-count="98">0 </div>
               
                <h4 class="count mt-3 mb-5">Quality Members</h4>
            </div>
         
          
        
        </div>
```

Comment: Please can you put the error you are getting. Thanks!

Comment: $('.counter') in the .counter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mounted() { $('.counter').each(/* whatever */) }
```

instead of

```
mounted: $('.counter').each(/* whatever */)
```

The way you have it, mounted is not a function (should be) but the return value of .each(), that's the problem. The whole point about using reactive frameworks like Vue is to NOT use imperative libraries like jquery, though, but I guess this was just for trying it out.